# Error creating folder: Permission denied

Tags: permissions

I am using VM Player for Ubuntu, then using WinSCP I need to copy the installer of a CMS to /var/www/html but it always says -

```
Error creating folder
Permission denied.
Error code: 3
Error message from server: Permission denied
```

Even when I try to create a folder it gives the same error. Thank you! I'm a student adnd this is for project purposes.

Comment: Did you try with sudo?

Comment: No, I don't. How?

Comment: What command are you using to copy the folders?

Answer (score 2):

That's because `/var` is owned by root, so you have to be *temporarily* root to access it ..

That's exactly what's the **sudo** command for, for making you look like another user, which is root by default.

The root user happens to have access to ***[everything on the system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)***, whether it belonged to you, root, or whatever ..

So, to create a folder in a folder that isn't yours, you use sudo.
In other words, you have to do the following.

1. Open a Terminal Window
2. Copy the installer using the command:

   ```
   sudo cp <installer_path> <directory_to_copy_to>
   ```

   (directory would be `/var/www/html` in your case)
3. You'll be prompted to enter your password, do it.

You're done!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have opened the WinSCP connection as root (which I don't recommend) you will need to transfer the file to somewhere that your regular user has write permission (such as your Ubuntu home directory). Then log in to the Ubuntu machine and move the file to the target directory using sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo` command to create the directory in var because it owned by root.

```
vfroot$ sudo mkdir SP
```